# Android WebView does not load new content on scroll end

Tags: android, webview, scroll, load

A part of my app is showing a website inside a WebView.
The website shows chunks of 20 items. When you scroll to the end, the next 20 items are shown. This works fine in any web browser.

In my WebView though, only the inital chunk is shown and nothing happens, when I scroll to the end.

The settings of the WebView:

```
binding?.webView?.settings?.let {
            it.javaScriptEnabled = true
            it.domStorageEnabled = true
            it.javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true
            it.setSupportMultipleWindows(false) // if true, hrefs with target _blank are not clickable in webview
        }
```

The Fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/web_view_refresh"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <com.facebook.shimmer.ShimmerFrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/web_view_loading"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:visibility="gone">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

               ***** OTHER COMPONENTS ******

            </LinearLayout>
        </com.facebook.shimmer.ShimmerFrameLayout>
        <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scroll_web_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/web_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
    </FrameLayout>
</androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

I tried to remove the webview from the NestedScrollView. Which resulted in laggy scrolling, but still no new content on scroll end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `true` two `properties`

```
binding?.webView?.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
binding?.webView?.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Thanks! That kinda helped. I removed the nestedScrollView and set the scrollbar. Now it works on some sub pages, but on some other in does not, which confuses me even more.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean with "inside Scrollbar"

Comment: Thank you, but this does not work at all, unfortunately.

Comment: Update: Seems that part of the problem is the website itself. So the approach of removing  `NestedScrollView` and set the scrollbar seems to be the right answer. Neverless, the scrolling expeience without the nestedScrollView is terrible, hence why I kinda need this to work with the nestedScrollView as well